# DB support for optimistic concurrency

Tags: jdbc, optimistic-concurrency

I have a classic scenario: two updates to the same record that are based on a previously ready value from this record.
I am working under the assumption of optimistic concurrency. It is not hard for me to implement the conditional update by myself- the question is whether I can rely on a certain API from the driver or the DB that will handle it for me?

Naturally, I Googled it, but all I seem to come up with are explanations of WHAT is optimistic concurrency, without mentioning code samples...

I am using JDBC data direct driver.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, JDBC doesn't have any support for optimistic concurrency. Optimistic concurrency is handled by JPA by using a dedicated `version` column to the table, and incrementing the version value each time an update is made. The update query looks like this:

```
update foo set ..., version = version + 1 
where id = :theId and version = :theVersionLoadedInMemory
```

If `executeUpdate()` returns 0 instead of 1, it means that someone else deleted the record, or updated it and thus incremented the version.

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, I stumbled upone this piece of documentation: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/resultset.html

Section 5.1.8 Concurrency Types, states that "To allow a higher level of concurrency, an updatable result set may be implemented so that it uses an optimistic concurrency control scheme" m\implying that certain drivers may choose to implement it OOTB.